# Building C++11 for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c++11, windows-phone-8

We're using a shared library (written in C++11). While some constructs of modern C++ are supported with VS2012 we cannot use Variadic templates, explicit etc.

VS2013 supports all the features we need, however we are not able to build a Windows Phone 8 App such that it uses the compiler from VS2013 as the SDK still uses the VS2012.

Will maybe this compiler CTP (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) help (so we could build in VS2012)? Or there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone SDK 8 is using Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler. Windows Phone SDK 8.1 will be using Visual Studio 2013 C++ compiler, and is expected to be released during Microsoft BUILD conference on April 2, 2014.

Comment: And it will be possible also to target Windows Phone 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check this video 
"Windows Phone 8 Native C/C++ Game Development"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6gYJFPvCSM

The Video goes through the process of bringing existing code base to windows phone application.

From the talk (and several others related from "Build")  there are 3 ways to do a C++ integration.

- C/C++ and DirectX
- WinRT Binding and Native C++ library
- WinRT only App

From the question it seems you have the second option.Windows Phone/8 does not allow direct C++ libraries without a WinRT binding.

So the VS2013 with Windows Phone 8 SDK should be able to build your library.

Search channel9.msdn.com for similar material

Hope that will help.